# Conditional probability -Basketball

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

How does the number of shots made by a player in a game get distribute if we are given that the number of shots missed equal to the number of shots scored?

data:
P(score)=$0.83$, P(miss)=$0.17$

no. of shots in a game  $Z\sim Poi(6)$

game duration: 48 min

$\underline{\textrm{My work so far:}}$

from what is given Y=no.of misses=no. of hits=X

so $X\sim Poi(6\cdot 0.83=4.98)$ and $Y\sim Poi(1.02)$

$$P(X|X=Y)=P(X=k,Y=k)/P(X=Y)=   \frac{P(X=k)P(Y=k)}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}  P(X=n)\cdot P(Y=n)}$$

The problem is that i dont sure if $P(X=Y)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}  P(X=n)\cdot P(Y=n)$.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  "How does the number of shots of a player in a game get divided by if we are given that the number of misses equal to the number of scores?"  doesn't make sense.  What data are you given?  What do you wish to compute?

Comment: i am sorry English isn't my first language. i want to find How does the number of shots made by a player in a game get distribute if we are given that the number of shots missed equal to the number of shots scored. the ive been given is  p(score)=0.83 p(miss)=0.17

no. of shots in a game Z~poi(6)

game duration: 48 min

Comment: Ok...and I gather that the number of shots is assumed to be poisson with $\lambda=6$?  You don't actually say that anywhere, and the fact that you bring up the length of a regulation game suggests that maybe you meant something else?  But assuming I have guessed correctly, then knowing that scores= misses tells us that an even number of shots were taken.  For each $N$ compute the probability that exactly  $2N$ shots  were taken and that of those exactly $N$ were scores and $N$ were misses, then use Bayes' Theorem.  The probability drops off very fast as $N$ grows.

Comment: you assumed correctly- poisson with λ=6. i didnt mean any thing with game duration it is just data given. How do i do this "For each N compute the probability that exactly 2N shots were taken and that of those exactly N were scores and N were misses" that is my problam

Comment: Where is the difficulty?  Let's say $N=1$.  Then $2N=2$.  The probability that he takes exactly $2$ shots is $0.0446$.  Conditioned on that, the probability that he gets exactly one score and one miss is $\binom 21\times .83^1\times .17^1=0.2822$.  Thus, for $N=1$ the value you want is $.0446\times 0.2822=0.01259$.  Now do this for more values of $N$.  You don't need many values of $N$...the probabilities rapidly become insignificant as $N$ grows.

Comment: but you didnt use the fact that is shots are poisson distributed.

Comment: I used that when I computed the probability that he took exactly two shots.  By Poisson that is $e^{-6}\times \frac {6^2}{2!}=0.044617539$ which, in my comment, I rounded to $.0446$

Comment: i dont think you are right. where is the condition?

Comment: What condition?  I was computing $p_1$:  the probability that our man throws exactly one score and one miss.  To do that I first compute the probability that he throws exactly $2$ shots (Poisson) and then, conditioned on that, the probability that of those two exactly one is a score and exactly one is a miss (binomial).  $p_1$ is then the product of those two values.  You need to do the same for $p_N$ (but, happily, you don't need very many $N$).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that "the number of shots made by a player "  refers to the total number of shots, scored and missed:  $Z = X + Y$

Then we want 
$$
\begin{align}
P(Z =z| X = Y)&=\frac{P(X = Y|Z=z) P(Z=z)}{P(X=Y)}\\
\tag{1}\end{align}
$$

Let's compute $P(X = Y|Z=z)$ . First, we note that this is zero if $z$ is odd.

Now, assuming $z$ is even, $P(X = Y|Z=z)$ corresponds to the event of having, in $z=2t$ tries of a Bernoulli experiment with hit probability $p$, $t$ misses and $t$ scores. The probability of this event is given by a Binomial: $\binom{z}{t} p^t (1-p)^t $

Then the numerator of $(1)$ is

$$ \binom{z}{z/2} (p q)^{z/2} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^z}{z!} \tag{2}$$

where $p=0.83$, $q=1-p$,  $\lambda = 6$

(actually, it's not clear what you mean by $Z∼Poi(6)$ and "game duration=48 minutes" - it would seem that the latter is not necessary - unless the poisson parameter is actually some rate  (scores per time unit) , but then the statement is confusing)

The denominator is just a normalization constant:

$$
\begin{align}
P(X=Y)&= 
\sum_{z \,{\rm even}} \binom{z}{z/2} (p q)^{z/2} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^z}{z!} \\
&=e^{-\lambda}  \sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{a^t }{(t!)^2} 
\end{align}
\tag3$$

with $a=p q \sqrt{\lambda}$. I'm not sure if that has a simple closed form expression.